# How to plot seperate bar graph for each repeated factors using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Given Data sets are :

```
df <- data.frame(var =c("a","b","c","a","b","d") , value = c(1:6))

> df
  var value
1   a     1
2   b     2
3   c     3
4   a     4
5   b     5
6   d     6
> str(df)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ var  : Factor w/ 4 levels "a","b","c","d": 1 2 3 1 2 4
 $ value: int  1 2 3 4 5 6
>
```

Here we see variable variables `a` and `b` repeated twice , our requirement is 
to plot bar graph for each variables but for variable `a` and `b` ,we need 
separate bar for each `a` and `b` .

i tried below code :

```
ggplot(data = df , aes(x = var , y = value)) +
       geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  geom_text(aes(label = value),color="white",fontface = "bold",size =2.5,vjust = 1.8)
```

here value of `a` and `b` stacked and ploted in single bar ,please help to fix this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new variable to map to the x-axis, it can just be a simple vector of 1 to N:

```
df$row_num = 1:nrow(df)

ggplot(data = df , aes(x = row_num , y = value, fill = var)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
    geom_text(aes(label = value),color="white",fontface = "bold",size =2.5,vjust = 1.8)
```

Output:

[image: Bar plot]

Comment: A suggestion: make row_num as factor: `df$row_num <- as.factor(1:nrow(df))`. Then add `scale_x_discrete(labels = var)` to the plot.